# Managing multiple CFCs together

Tags: multithreading, inheritance, coldfusion, cfc, application.cfc

I am having an application which includes multiple CFCs (more than 100 CFCs). I would like to initiate these CFCs when the application get started so that I can use its instances anywhere in the system. Can I know what is best way to initialize these CFCs together? Any option available to initialize the all CFCs dynamically?

Comment: Why? The cost of instantiating an object is negligible.

Comment: If some of these CFCs have dependencies on others, you may want to look into a way to handle dependency injection. DI/1 would be a good place to start.

Comment: If at least one of these cfc's takes arguments in its init method, this may be a bad idea.

Comment: Also a bad idea if any of them use any sort of internal state.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about static components, i.e. singletons.

To initialize a component once, use the `onApplicationStart` event in your `Application.cfc` and store the component in the persistent `APPLICATION` scope. This event function is executed (thread-safe) on the first request. You will then refer to the components stored in the APPLICATION scope in your templates.

You can initialize components dynamically, e.g.

```
componentPath = "yourPath.toThe.Component";
componentName = listLast(componentPath, ".");
APPLICATION[componentName] = createObject("component", componentPath).init();
```

You could retrieve a list of all .cfc files in a given directory and then loop over them with the code above.